# Read data from SQL Server with dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

```
var query = "SELECT OrderNo, PlannedQuantity, CompletedQuantity, IsClosed" + 
            " FROM Order1 WHERE OrderNo =:orderNo";

var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "orderNo", orderNo } };

using (var reader = ExecuteDatabaseReader(query, arguments)) 
{
     if (reader.Read()) 
     {  
         return GetOrderFromReader(reader); 
     }
} 

static IDataReader ExecuteDatabaseReader(string query, IDictionary<string, object> arguments) 
{
     return null; 
}
```

Comment: using (var reader = ExecuteDatabaseReader(query, arguments))
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    return GetOrderFromReader(reader);
                }
            }
 static IDataReader ExecuteDatabaseReader(string query, IDictionary<string, object> arguments)
        {
          return null;
        }

Comment: Please add a description of what you're trying to achieve, the problems you are facing and any solutions you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a method like below. Of cource code below is a simple code and it needs to be very better. For example, I haven't managed to close and dispose the connection.

```
static IDataReader ExecuteDatabaseReader(string query, IDictionary < string, object > arguments) {

    var conn = new SqlConnection(your_connection_string);

    conn.Open();
    var commadn = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = query;

    foreach(var key in arguments.Keys) {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(key, arguments[key]);
    }

    return command.ExecuteReader();

}
```

One important notes about parameters, I don't know what your RDBMS is if it's SQL Server you need to define your parameters with `@` sign.

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 dictionary.Add("@Id", 1);
 dictionary.Add("@Name", "Name");
```